# Facebook mobile app keeps connecting to googleplay

Tags: android

I made a php facebook application. The app looks good on desktop facebook. But when I wanna look at it from my android phone, instead of seeing my facebook application/site it redirects me to google play, where i dont have any application.. How can i fix that?

Comment: Please give more information and post some code also so we can help you more.

Comment: Can you explain with some code block. Thanks

Comment: This is a php application/site. Even a index.php with only 1 echo line, and nothinh othersendme to google play market. But it works on desktop facebook, but not on mobile facebook. Maybe because I have set this application for android also( settings for android: package name....) . Do I need to create another facebook application seperately?